# python for audio file creation

Tags: python, audio, random

The project is to generate multiple sports starting sequence audio of: "on your marks"/pause1/"set"/pause2/"gunshot sound".

Pause1 thresholds 10-19 sec, pause2 0.9-2.1 sec.
"" are existing individual.mp3 files.

Would like to generate 30 random audio files using a code that match the parameters.

```
import random
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

# Load audio files
on_your_marks = AudioSegment.from_file("C:\\Users\\Kolbi\\Downloads\\Starting gun\\1\\ON YOUR MARKS DASH.mp3")
set_sound = AudioSegment.from_file("C:\\Users\\Kolbi\\Downloads\\Starting gun\\1\\SET DASH.mp3")
gun_sound = AudioSegment.from_file("C:\\Users\\Kolbi\\Downloads\\Starting gun\\1\\gun sound3.mp3")

# Define lower and upper limits for pause durations in milliseconds
on_your_marks_lower_limit = 10000  # 10 seconds
on_your_marks_upper_limit = 19500  # 19.5 seconds
set_gun_lower_limit = 1000  # 1 second
set_gun_upper_limit = 2500  # 2.5 seconds

# Generate the soundtrack
play(on_your_marks)

# Generate random pause duration before "SET" sound
on_your_marks_pause_duration = random.randint(on_your_marks_lower_limit, on_your_marks_upper_limit)

AudioSegment.silent(duration=on_your_marks_pause_duration).export("C:\\Users\\Kolbi\\Downloads\\Starting gun\\1\\pause1.wav", format="wav")

pause1 = AudioSegment.from_file("C:\\Users\\Kolbi\\Downloads\\Starting gun\\1\\pause1.wav")

play(pause1)

# Play "SET" sound
play(set_sound)

# Generate random pause duration before "GUN" sound
set_gun_pause_duration = random.randint(set_gun_lower_limit, set_gun_upper_limit)

AudioSegment.silent(duration=set_gun_pause_duration).export("C:\\Users\\Kolbi\\Downloads\\Starting gun\\1\\pause2.wav", format="wav")

pause2 = AudioSegment.from_file("C:\\Users\\Kolbi\\Downloads\\Starting gun\\1\\pause2.wav")

play(pause2)

# Play "GUN" sound
play(gun_sound)
```

Answer (score -1):

To generate multiple sports starting sequence audio files with random pause durations, you can modify the code as follows:

```py
import random
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

# Load audio files
on_your_marks = AudioSegment.from_file("C:/Users/Kolbi/Downloads/Starting gun/1/ON YOUR MARKS DASH.mp3")
set_sound = AudioSegment.from_file("C:/Users/Kolbi/Downloads/Starting gun/1/SET DASH.mp3")
gun_sound = AudioSegment.from_file("C:/Users/Kolbi/Downloads/Starting gun/1/gun sound3.mp3")

# Define lower and upper limits for pause durations in milliseconds
on_your_marks_lower_limit = 10000  # 10 seconds
on_your_marks_upper_limit = 19500  # 19.5 seconds
set_gun_lower_limit = 900  # 0.9 seconds
set_gun_upper_limit = 2100  # 2.1 seconds

# Generate multiple audio files
for i in range(30):
    print(f"Generating audio file {i+1}")
    
    # Generate random pause duration before "SET" sound
    on_your_marks_pause_duration = random.randint(on_your_marks_lower_limit, on_your_marks_upper_limit)
    pause1 = AudioSegment.silent(duration=on_your_marks_pause_duration)
    
    # Generate random pause duration before "GUN" sound
    set_gun_pause_duration = random.randint(set_gun_lower_limit, set_gun_upper_limit)
    pause2 = AudioSegment.silent(duration=set_gun_pause_duration)
    
    # Concatenate audio segments to generate the soundtrack
    soundtrack = on_your_marks + pause1 + set_sound + pause2 + gun_sound
    
    # Export the soundtrack to a WAV file
    soundtrack.export(f"C:/Users/Kolbi/Downloads/Starting gun/1/audio_{i+1}.wav", format="wav")

    print(f"Audio file {i+1} generated")

print("Generation completed")
```

This code will generate 30 random audio files, each containing the sports starting sequence with different pause durations. The pause durations are randomly generated within the specified lower and upper limits. The resulting audio files will be saved as `audio_1.wav`, `audio_2.wav`, and so on, in the specified directory.

Make sure to adjust the file paths in the code to match the correct locations of your audio files.